# Hide password with dots for an edittext in android

Tags: android

I am trying to hide the password in edittext and the code is :

```
text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

text.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

The same code is working in my other application.

Can somebody help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it is working in your other application, the issue is not with this little code piece.

Comment: Yes, i was setting the edittext as singleline. my problem is soved.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        />
```

Hope its help.

Answer (score 2):

change the edittext input type property to text password in xml.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

As the original poster mentioned in a comment, calling `setSingleLine (boolean singleLine)` resets the `EditText` settings, so you'll have to call that first and after that set custom settings like the password `InputType`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSingleLine(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

To hide password programatically add this line below oncreate android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.TEXT_SHOW_PASSWORD, 0);